# Finding the value of the constants c and v from the density function

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

I want to know how to find the value of the both constants c and v from this function. I know if there was only one constant, say, c, you'll just need to integrate it and equate to 1. But I'm lost on how to do it if there were 2 missing constants.

Even a hint would be appreciated!

$\mathcal {f(x)} $ = \begin{cases} cx^v, 0<x<5 \\
0, \text{elsewhere}\\ \end{cases}

Comment: You're still only integrating over $x$ so you do it the same way as before.  To turn this function into a probability density function you'll find that $c$ can be any positive number.

Comment: Your instinct is right; it's not possible to determine $c$ or $v$ as fixed numbers, because the problem essentially has a free variable. For every $v > -1$, there is a corresponding $c$ that would yield a valid probability density.